# I have created a Web Api project using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a cshtml view page with its get method in MVC controller script is written bellow in cshtml file. I have placed a button `Register New User` when I click that button it should redirect to register HTML page for that I have used `$state.go`. I have created a module named `app.js` and register.js to call the post method register in API controller.
But the problem is by clicking the `Register New User` button the page is not reloaded to `Register.html`.
Someone help me with this problem
**cshtml code**

```
                <input id="Password" type="text" ng-model="Emp.Password" placeholder="Password" required /></br>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" /></br>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></br>

            </div>
```

```
        <input type="button" ng-click="Register()" value="Register New User" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    // var myapp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
    (function (app) {
        'use strict';

        app.controller("LoginController", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window", "$state", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, $state) {

            $scope.Emp = {};
            console.log("cont mvc");
            $scope.Submit = function (Emp) {
                console.log("inside", $scope.Emp);
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '/Webapplication2/Test/Login',
                    data: $scope.Emp,
                })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log("response", response.data);
                    //$window.location.href = '/Home/Display';
                    if (response.data == "CORRECT UserName and Password") {
                        console.log("if condition")
                        alert("CORRECT UserName and Password");
                        //$state.go("Display");
                        //$window.location.href = '/WebApplication2/Test/Display';


                        $window.alert("Hello " + $scope.Emp.UserName);
                    }
                    else if (response.data == "INCORRECT UserName or Password") {
                        alert("INCORRECT UserName or Password");
                    }
                })
            }
            $scope.Register = function () {
                console.log("reg button");
                $state.go('Register');
                //$window.location.href = '/Webapplication2/Test/Register';
            }
        }]);
    })(angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']));
</script>
```

**Module app.js code**

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$StateProvider', '$UrlRouteProvider', '$state', '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$logProvider',
    function ($StateProvider, $UrlRouteProvider, $state, $scope, $http, $location, $window, $logProvider) {
        console.log("modulejs");
        $UrlRouteProvider.otherwise("/Login");

        $StateProvider
        .state('Login', {
            url: 'Home/Login',
            templateUrl: "/Views/Home/Login.cshtml",
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })



        .state('Register', {
            url: 'Test/Register',

            templateUrl: "/Views/Test/Register.html",
            controller: 'RegisterController'
        })

    }])
```

})();
**Register.js code**
(function (app)
{

```
console.log("cont register");
app.controller("RegisterController", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,$state) {
    console.log("cont2");
    $scope.Submit = function (Emp) {
        console.log("inside", Emp);
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/Webapplication2/Test/Register',
            data: $scope.Emp,
        })

        .then(function (response) {
            //$window.location.href = '/Webapplication2/Test/Display';
            //$msgbox.alert("Hello " + $scope.Emp.UserName);
            $window.alert("Hello " + $scope.Emp.UserName);
        })
    }
    $scope.Login = function () {
        console.log("login button")
        $state.go('Login');
        //$window.location.href = '/Webapplication2/Test/Login';
    }
});
})(angular.module('myApp',[]));
```

Comment: Register happening ah? no console error right?

Answer (score 0):

Why you doing **IIFE** with `angular.module` as parameter.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); // app is global variable we can refer anywhere by the `window`

  // here already refer the app module
 app.controller("RegisterController", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,$state) {
       //...... code
})(angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']));
```

Remove your **IIFE** parameter change your controller like below.

```
 app.controller("RegisterController",["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window","$state", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,$state) {
           //...... code
    }]);
```

or

```
(function () {

  app.controller("RegisterController",["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window","$state", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,$state) {
               //...... code
        }])
 }());
```

Comment: Sir im receving this error in console........Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Comment: Yes ......But i had made the changes but still the function is not called

Comment: When i click on the "Register New User" button it should hit on Register in app,js then it should call to Register.js on that register.js i have written to load Register.html

Comment: did u inject ng-app="myApp" and  ng-controller="RegisterController" directives in your cshtml

Comment: join chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145171/angularjs-discussion

Comment: I gave you permission

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: you can chat.. now try.

Comment: Sry i tried to send the whole project but its cant be sent. So i sent all the contents seperately

Comment: Check your mail.. Make every file separate. Download ui-router file. etc..